# Ionic emulator not posting to localhost api

Tags: c#, ionic-framework

I have a localhost API running on `127.0.0.1` and my app on the emulator posting to `10.0.2.2` which gives the **error** :

> Http failure response for 'api path'

but it does not reach the API.

However, when doing a `GET` via chrome it reaches the API.

`CORS` has been enabled on the API.

Comment: you can specify the api path when performing http request

Comment: @Naseer I am specifying the path, the issue is it reaches the api from emulator chrome but not from ionic

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026