# Http.get() working but not working in build(Release/Debug) in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying get data from a simple api, it works fine in **ionic serve**(browser) , But when i build the app http call does not work. my Code is

```
this.http.get("http://example.com/api/routes").subscribe(response => {
 this.routes = response["routes"];
 for (let x in this.routes) {
 let a = this.routes[x].rou_stops;
 let b = a.split(",");
          for (let y in b) {
            this.newCit.push(b[y]);

          }
        }
   });
```

please help with this issue.

Comment: Any runtime error?

Comment: No sir, there are no runtime errors.

Comment: Are you getting any error you device debug console?

Comment: No sir @NajamUsSaqib , no any errors in debug

Comment: This is aloso not working form me. for v 7

Comment: @ArindamSarkar check the api wether its https:// not http://

Comment: it's https:// I have check my one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am Guessing that your are getting this because of android changes its http architecture.

to make it working on Android go to your project root folder.

yourAppFolder > resources > android > xml > network_security_config.xml
Change your network security config to blow code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: happy to hear that. :)

Comment: I don't have an xml folder

Comment: what directory structure you have? and which version of IONIC are you using?

Answer (score 3):

**IONIC 5 UPDATE**

I had the same issue in Ionic 5 but made more complicated by the fact that HttpClient was not catching the error (I was simply getting back an unknown failed response).

In order to see that it was indeed a **cleartext** error I first had to change HttpClient for the Native HTTP plugin.

In Ionic 5 you can now enable cleartext in the capacitor.config.json file or replace the existing json file with a .ts version:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
                 appId: 'com.company.appname',
                 appName: 'My Capacitor App',
                 webDir: 'www',
                 server: {
                           'cleartext': true
                         }
              };

export default config;
```

[docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config#schema)

Comment: ITS WORKED, you save my days. I have used the same Angular HttpClient.

Comment: This also resolved an SocketIO and Ionic issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [**Native HTTP plugin**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) for the device use cases:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
npm install @ionic-native/http
```

usage from the doc:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private http: HTTP) {}

...

this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
```

Comment: i used import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";  is it a problem? it worked before without an issue. :(

Comment: Sometimes browser-based `HttpClient` doesn't work on the native device. At that time we need to use the native Http plugin.

Comment: It worked but, some extra update updates needed. thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think configuration change is better and it is a new thing and I have learned it today.

Comment: Not related to OP. I've had to use this plugin in the past, but IONIC5 now allows for HTTP Requests to be handled by Angular HttpClient and Interceptors (thank god).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on the Ionic 4 app.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers, while they can work, are **not** safe options, since they open up non-https traffic.

cleartext is only meant for local testing with live-reload, and **should not** be used for production apps.

The real solution would be to use HTTPS endpoints or setup HTTPS on your own server via let's encrypt.