# ionic 3 [object object] not able to parse data in Android P

Tags: angular, object, ionic-framework, android-9.0-pie

I am new to ionic.

I am developing a basic informational app.

I am running it on the browser, emulator, real device it works perfectly but then I tried to run it on Android version 9 it didn't work.

It returns **[object object]** While login.

I take input from **ion-input**. In all lower versions, users can fill the detail but in Android P when I click to fill the detail it didn't work. I can't write anything. But after clicking the button I can fill the detail.

When all field is written and on login, it returns **[object object]**.

[image]

In all lower versions of Android, it works perfectly. Users can log in.

**auth-service.ts**

```js
postData(credentials, type) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let data: Observable<any> = this.http.post(baseURL + type, credentials);

      data.subscribe(response => {
        // console.log("Auth POST Response : " , response);
        for (let data of response) {
          resolve(data);
        }
      }, err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
        reject(err);
      }, () => {
        console.log('completed');
      });

    });
  }
```

**login.ts**

```js
login() {
      let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        spinner: 'circles',
        content: 'Please wait...'
      });
      loading.present();

      let postData = new FormData();
      postData.append('contact_no', this.userData.contact_no);
      postData.append('password', this.userData.password);
      postData.append('fcm_id', this.userData.fcm_id);
      postData.append('imei_no', this.deviceId);

      this.authService.postData(postData, "login.php").then((result) => {
        this.responseData = result;
        console.log("res : ", this.responseData);
        this.success = this.responseData.success;
          console.log("this.success : ", this.success);
          if (this.success == 1) {
            let userDeatil = this.responseData.user_data;
            this.userId = this.responseData.user_id;
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDeatil));
            loading.dismiss();
            this.navCtrl
              .push(TabsPage)
              .then(() => {
                const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
                this.navCtrl.remove(index);
              });
            // this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
          } else {
            this.message = this.responseData.message;
            loading.dismiss();
            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: this.message,
              duration: 2000,
              position: 'bottom'
            });
            toast.present(toast);
          }
      }, (err) => {
        loading.dismiss();
        console.log("Error", err);
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: err,
          duration: 2000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });
        toast.present(toast);
      });
  }
```

**network_security_config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "sujagSindhiSamiti",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Check My Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026 If it Helps Please Upvote it.

Comment: Please check my question I updated it.My network_security_config.xml  @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: It's not working @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: It is your network config issue. Please update your network file as i said in my answer to that question. It will work.

Comment: I updated it but while running in CLI it automatically changes the code to my original file @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: Can you share your ionic cli and pluggins details

Comment: Please check it. It's updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206503/discussion-between-najam-us-saqib-and-unnati-patadia).

Comment: I think nothing as coding will difer,but in the version of the mobile is the difference,the form data imei_no can differ,check if it is being send normally or there is a problem in it.

Comment: it sends normally @MostafaHarb

Comment: I have one question( this obeject object that is appearing is from success side or fail side??(from this.success or this.message)

Comment: It's appearing from `err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
        reject(err);` from **postData(credentials, type)** function  @MostafaHarb

Comment: Ok still 1 question, is the website you are trying to send data to https?(have and ssl certificate)? If not https then its the problem since android pie don't accept api requests without https requests for security.(if no tell me to send you the solution).

Comment: It's not https.@MostafaHarb

Comment: I have already added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: It's solved. I have changed http to https. Thanks! @MostafaHarb

Comment: @MostafaHarb I have one another issue can you please help me with that. In android pi when user touch on **ion-input** to write username and password it didn't work. Users can't write any input but after clicking on the button.  **ion-input** is writable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206560/discussion-between-unnati-patadia-and-mostafa-harb).

Comment: I am not getting the point. 0096176303389. If you want thats my whatsapp and we could talk better andfaster there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add network_security_config.xml path and usesCleartextTraffic your config.xml under platform android
something like this:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
  <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
</edit-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line it should work

```
    this.responseData = result;

    this.responseData = JSON.parse(result);
            OR 
    this.responseData = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Comment: I didn't get any response. it returns an error at `err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
        reject(err);
      }` in postData(credentials, type) function