# Ionic5 angular9 vendor-es2015.js ERROR [object Object]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-httpclient

I created an apk using ionic 5 and angular 9 that accesses a server with php mysql backend. When using a device with android 7 and 8 or using a browser the application works okay. When using a device with android 9+ it seems to fail to access the internet. Testing the app using an emulator with android 9+, the debugger returns the error

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js: Line 44076 : ERROR [object Object]
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(44076)] “ERROR [object Object]”, source: http://localhost/vendor-es2015.js (44076)
```

when attempting to post to the server.

What could be the issue?

Comment: check your `AndroidManifest.xml` for internet Permission. otherwise try this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/60210673/5909026

Comment: hi @NajamUsSaqib, internet permissions are referenced in the android Manifest. The application works fine on Android 7 and 8

Comment: check my answer on other post i mentioned in my previous comment.