# Ionic 4 or Ionic 5 Login

Tags: angular, rest, authentication, ionic-framework

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ejp4.png)

does anyone have an example about an ionic login but consuming a rest service get. I have a project, but a error 404 don't let me move on my project

Comment: 404 probably means you have set the rest end point , try opening the network tab in chrome and checking where your app is requesting

Comment: my friend, in the publication I have the image of the console and the error, it is no longer 404

Comment: You are on an android emulator, right?You need to change your config.xml to accept clear text requests.

Comment: I am testing it on my device, the console is from chrome developer, which is being updated at the same time with my device. The other thing is that you already configure the config.xml, but follow the same of clear text requests

Comment: i put this in my config.xml

Comment: <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>

Comment: Check my Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026

Comment: I solved it, but now it's giving me an error about the cors

Comment: how the enable this?