# Socket io works in ionic serve but not work on the actual device after build in ionic cordova

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Socket io works in ionic serve but not work on the actual device after building in ionic cordova

Comment: The socket url is still locslhost or u uploaded it to live server?

Comment: socket URL(like 'http://192.168.0.103:444') open and I am working on the same wifi network

And Also socket url work on mobile brower html pages only issue with build APK

Comment: during ionic serve browser testing it's working but debug apk file install in android mobile  then it's not work

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026

Comment: happy to hear that.  Please upvote .