# Ionic v5 not connecting to Rest API using Capacitor

Tags: http, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using http module to access to my API server from a Service:

```
loadSongs(): Observable<Song[]> {
    console.log("Cargando canciones desde "+apiUrl);
return this.http.get<Song[]>(apiUrl+'/songs')
  .pipe(
            tap(song => {
                console.log('fetched songs')
            }),
    catchError(this.handleError('getSongs', []))
  );
}
```

Using ionic serve works perfect, but using capacitor to run on Android it doesn't work. Chrome Inspector doesn't show any error:

```
...another messages...
 -Cargando canciones desde https://comboiapp.es:3000
-capacitor-runtime.js:397 native App.addListener (#45780662)
```

That's all.
Any idea?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried that solution, but still the same problem. I forgot to say access is HTTPS