# Problem to make requests on my ionic app w/ capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have this ionic app that consumes from a server api (Spring). When i use capacitor to use the android version it works fine on the emulator from android studio, but when using a real device the http requests doesn't work. It retrives the message: "Msg: Status: 0, Message: Http failure response for http:///login: 0 Unknown Error". Things i tried: Disabled the firewall and use the same wi-fi from server.
[message from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKjRN.jpg)

Comment: Check This Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026

Comment: Check you developer console error.. you will have a bit more clarity as to why your request is failing.. also check the network tab.. I suspect this might be because of CORS settings.

Comment: I tried Najam's aproach. There is something strange on it. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.silkimen.cordovahttp.CordovaHttpPlugin. I installed the plugin and it says it can't find the class. I can guess it's related to my cordova, since i can't run on my project. I will try again later.