# Problem in running the post method in the android app using ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have successfully taken build using ionic cordova build android. After installing the app in my mobile, for checking the enquiry. The post method method is not saved in the DB. So I taken the browser build for checking the error, but the browser is working fine.

Homepage.component.ts

```
  onSubmit(form) {
    let addurl;
      addurl = this._https.enquiry(this.homecontents);
   
    addurl.subscribe(success => {
      form.form.markAsPristine();
      form.resetForm();
     
    });
  }
```

Http.service.ts

```
 enquiry(senddata){
    return this.http.post(this.url_api+"enquiry",senddata);
  }
```

Browser:
[In browser the post method is working fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgaMJ.gif)

Android:

[In the ionic after taking the build and check the post method its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VEGi.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to provide some code, possibly error logs (e.g. run the app in Android studio) otherwise helping you becomes difficult.

Comment: Now I have edited my question, can you please help me.

Comment: You can use remote debugging to check if the request is sent. It is hard to say what could be wrong with less code. For example if you compare the local serve (ng serve) with a android build, the compilation is a bit different. so you may check also the build you use to create the android build to (dist folder, the stuff you sync to cordova)

Comment: You can try with the command `ionic cordova run android -lc --device`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59310320/5909026

Comment: what is your `url_api` ??